# comparing strings alphabetically in ruby goes wrong

Tags: ruby, search

I am developing a binary search algorithm that searches through a string array, however, at some point in my search "Canacee" is evaluated than being lower alphabetically than "administrate". Does anybody know why this is happening? 
My code:

```
class Array
def binary_search(val, low=0, high=(length - 1))
    return false if high < low
    mid = (low + high) / 2
    midvalue = self[mid].downcase.strip

    value = self[mid] <=> val
    printf "%s \t %s \t %d \t %d\n", midvalue, val, mid, value
    case
    when value==0 then return true
    when value > 0 then binary_search(val, low, mid-1)
    when value < 0 then binary_search(val, mid+1, high)
    end
  end
end

path = ARGV.length > 0 ? ARGV[0] : '/words'
entries = File.read(path).split("\n")

if entries.binary_search("administrate")
  printf "yes"
else
 printf "no"
end
```

However, I am not able to find the word "administrate" which is in the word file. 
This is the output I get:

```
mogitocia    administrate    117467      1 
dysoxidation     administrate    58733   1 
canacee      administrate    29366   -1 
counterdistinction   administrate    44049   1 
citification     administrate    36707   1
cetomorphic      administrate    33036   1
castellanship    administrate    31201   1
carboxylase      administrate    30283   1
capelet      administrate    29824   1
cankery      administrate    29595   1
candied      administrate    29480   1
cancelation      administrate    29423   1
canalling    administrate    29394   1
canalage     administrate    29380   1
canadine     administrate    29373   1
canadian     administrate    29369   -1
canadianization      administrate    29371   -1
canadianize      administrate    29372   -1
```

Comment: You need to supply your input also.

Comment: Also, don't use a binary search on an array when you have hashes available to you. The hash will always win.

Comment: Also, you might be interested to know that ruby 2.0 has a built-in binary search method for arrays: `ary.bsearch {|x| "administrate" <=> x }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
value = self[mid] <=> val
```

to

```
value = midvalue <=> val
```

otherwise you are using the un-downcased `self[mid]`, so naturally `'C'` comes before `'a'` in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).